# Alternatives to Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I lost days of work I did on Google Apps Script, just because I opened an old tab on my browser with code from a week earlier.

I am upset, because it was a lot of code, and I do not have time to reproduce it all. In the past, this problem was easy to solve, because you would just look at the version history. But Google purposefully removed that feature from the new editor, without replacing it, leading to hours/days of lost productivity because of simple mistakes like this. I want to protest by considering an alternative platform. Does such a platform exist?

Comment: There is a version history, but now you have to manually save your versions (Google no longer automatically saves the most recent version as was the case with the old IDE). See [Versions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/versions).

Answer (score 0):

What is the task you are trying to do with Google Apps Script exactly?

If you want to process data within the Google Workspace like manipulating data on Google Sheets, or automating Gmail, Google Apps Script is your only reasonable choice.

If you are willing to export the data to a format like CSV, you have a lot more choices, like Python and other scripting languages.

If you want to migrate away from Google Workspace, Microsoft Office has this feature similar to Google Apps Script.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/explore-with-script-lab